# docker desktop swarm service port not exposed (ingress mode)

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I'm trying to apply a demo like in the article :

[Scale ASP.NET Core Apps with Docker Swarm Mode](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/scale-asp-net-core-apps-with-docker-swarm-mode)

Unfortunately after creating and start the service on docker swarm , I couldn't access the api http://localhost:5000/api/token . However, when I call the api in the running container  (using **docker exec**) or creating the service using **host** mode every thing goes OK.

**Note** : I'm trying using docker desktop in my local machine , so I enabled swarm mode using the following command

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.56.1
```

where 192.168.56.1 is the VirtualBox ip

**Edit** : Corresponding container:

[image]

Service port configuration:

[image]

thanks in advance .

Comment: Is this docker desktop using toolbox and `docker-machine`?

Comment: thanks for your response @BMitch  , I don't thinks so,when I'm trying , 'docker-machine' command , Im getting it is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: In that case I'm confused by the VirtualBox reference since that was last used with `docker-machine`. Current versions of Docker for Win and Mac use hyperv and xhyve under the covers and you shouldn't be seeing the IP of the Docker VM in VirtualBox.

Comment: Screenshots are rather illegible, and remove the ability for others to search on your question. Please post as code formatted text instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the output of `docker ps` command, my guess is that something has not been done correctly with the following command.

```
docker service create --publish 5000:5000 --name tokengen tokengen-img
```

Comment: Thanks for response , I edited the question to add it

Comment: Under the ports section, it is blank, which effectively means the publishing did not work. Also I see the target port as 80 and published port as 5000, which does not sit well with the  `--publish 5000:5000`. So maybe the service create was not run correctly or did not create the required service.

Comment: thanks again @Sreekanth , in fact I published it using --publish 5000:80 , and inside the container it works normally